# Why are the names different in "/etc/HOSTNAME" file and hostname command in SLES11SP3?

Tags: linux, hostname, suse, sles

My `OS` is `SuSE(SLES11, SP3)`, executing the `hostname` command:

```
# hostname
lxc-dl580-g8-1
```

But the name in `/etc/HOSTNAME` file is different?

```
# cat /etc/HOSTNAME
linux-2pny.site
```

Why are the names different in `/etc/HOSTNAME` file and `hostname` command? If I want to modify the host name, how should I do?

Comment: AFAIK, nothing uses `/etc/HOSTNAME`.  Are you mistyping `/etc/hostname` (all lowercase)?  do you also have an `/etc/hostname` file containing `lxc-dl580-g8-1`?

Comment: @cas: No. In my `SLES`, there is only `/etc/HOSTNAME`, no `/etc/hostname`.

Comment: do you get your host's IP address from DHCP? the hostname is probably being set by your dhcp client.  or possible from DNS or from `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: BTW, according to a quick google search, not even SLES uses `/etc/HOSTNAME`.  e.g. google for 'change hostname on SLES' and all results will mention `/etc/hostname`.   if the all-caps file exists it will be because you created it.

Comment: @cas: Oh, yes, the IP is obtained from dhcp. But why `hostname` command display another name?

Comment: @cas: I don't create /etc/HOSTNAME on purpose, not sure which installation step created it.

Comment: as i  said, the dhcp client may be setting the host name when it gets the DHCP details (IP address, network, gateway, DNS server, etc) from the DHCP server.  or system startup scripts may be setting from DNS or `/etc/hosts`.  there are many ways it *might* be being set.

Comment: but none of that matters much.  `/etc/hostname` is the correct filename.  run `mv /etc/HOSTNAME /etc/hostname`.  then reboot.

Comment: BTW, unless you actually own that domain name `linux-2pny.site` (i.e. you have paid for and/or registered it with the owners of the `.site` domain), **DO NOT USE IT**.  Use a `.local` domain name instead.    `.site` does not belong to you.